# Prevent row checkbox from overlapping table header in CSS

Tags: css, tableheader

So I have a table in my page that has a a column that contains either a checkbox or a search icon. My problem now is if I scroll down my table contents, the search icon or checkbox is seen on the table header, how can I hide it?

This is my CSS:

```
<style lang="scss">
    .ui-table-header-row{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#dbb100;
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

And the output is like this:

[image]

How can I attain my goal?

Comment: Please provide the rest of your HTML markup and CSS styles, there's not enough here to debug the problem.

Comment: @kfedorov91 as per my debugging, this part affects the header of my table.

Comment: @ramedju yes, but we have no idea what the rest of your page is doing. Please share the rest of the html and css.

Comment: @LukeFlego Thanks all. I have figured it out. I just added `z-index` on my CSS, please see my answer below :) And my issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the inputs. I have just added this on my CSS and it do the trick :)

```
<style lang="scss">
    .ui-table-header-row{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#dbb100;
        color:#fff;
    }
   .ui-table-header-cell{
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```